# converting LINQ query result to int

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I've written a LINQ query that should return an int value. but I'm not able to convert this value to int and an exception occured:
**Unable to cast object of type 'QuickRoutes.DAL.RouteLinq' to type 'System.IConvertible'.**
this is my LINQ :

```
var res = (from p in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                       orderby p.RouteId descending
                       select p).Take(1);
```

and the exception occures here:

```
 route.Id =Convert.ToInt32(res.FirstOrDefault());
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are selecting a routeLinq object...instead select the property that corresponds to the int value u r interested in

Answer (score 10, accepted):

that is because `res.FirstOrDefault()` returns a `RouteLinqs` type object, because you are using `select p` , you may select a field using `select p.FieldName`, where FieldName is the property you require for conversion, which is probably `RouteId`

You may want to query the particular field in your linq query.

```
var res = (from p in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                       orderby p.RouteId descending
                       select p.RouteId).Take(1); //p.RouteID or any field you want.
```

Or with your current query, you may do:

```
 route.Id =Convert.ToInt32(res.FirstOrDefault().RouteID);
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're selecting the max route id, so why not just do:

```
route.Id = aspdb.RouteLinqs.Max(x => x.RouteId);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code should work:

```
route.Id = Convert.ToInt32((res.FirstOrDefault()).FieldName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your is but `RouteLinqs` is defined, but perhaps you are looking to select a specific object from the class `RouteLinqs`.

```
var res = (from p in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                   orderby p.RouteId descending
                   select p.SomeProperty).Take(1);
```

In this case `p` is a single item of `RouteLinqs` and p.SomeProperty should be your int value.

Answer (score 0):

First make linq :

```
IQueryable<int> query = (from p in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                           orderby p.RouteId descending
                           select p.Id);
```

Than run:

```
 int result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

In 1 command:

```
int result = (from p in aspdb.RouteLinqs
                           orderby p.RouteId descending
                           select p.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```